# How to solve this problem on the number line?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-line

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to solve this problem,
I have tried to work with some numbers, but I find many ways to do it, I do not arrive at anything concrete.

**According to the information given in the attached number line, which of the following statements is (are) true?**
$$I) n^4 > \frac{n}{4}$$
$$II) 2n<n$$
$$III)n^{(-3)} > n^2$$
$$IV) (n - \frac{1}{n})^{(-2)} <n^{(-3)}$$

[image]

Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LMxT.png

Comment: Okay, we know that $n^2 < n < \frac 1n$ that's pretty unusual.  Can you deduce what that might mean?

Comment: Remember if $a< b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$.  And if $0<a$ and $c > 1$ then $a < ac < ac^2 < ac^3 < .........$.  And if $0< a < b$ then $a^2 =a\cdot b < a\cdot b =b^2$ and so on.

Comment: Note the only time $2n < n$ is when $n < 0$.  Is $n< 0$?

Comment: I'm blocked sorry

Comment: Think it out.  $x^2 \ge 0$.  If $0 < x < 1$ then $x^2 < x$ but if $x>1$ then $x < x^2$.  Also if $x > 1$ then $0 < \frac 1x < 1$ and vice versa, if $0 < x < 1$ then $\frac 1x > 1$.  So you have $n^2 < n < n^{-1}$.  That tells us something very important.  That one thing will make most of those straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for answering, no matter how much I analyze what you have written to me, I lose.
Could you answer for each option please?
example i) is true because ....or is false because....

Comment: I think I'm dizzy thinking that it can't be any real except zero

Comment: Oh, it *can't* be $0$.  If it were $0$ then $n^2 = n$ and $n^{-1}$ would be undefined.  But it could be $n=\frac 12$.  If $n = \frac 12$ then $n^2 = \frac 14; n =\frac 12;$ and $n^{-1} = 2$ and we *would* have $n^2 < n < n^{-1}$.  But that's only one possible value $n$ can be.  What *other* values can we have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.... we have $n^2 < n < n^{-1}$.

Now $n^2 \ge 0$ so we have $0 \le n^2 < n < n^{-1}$ so $n > 0$.

Since $n > 0$ we can multiply or divide by $n$ and maintain the inequality.

If we multiply all by $n$ we get $n^2\cdot n < n\cdot n < n^{-1}\cdot n$ or $n^3 < n^2 < 1$ and if we divide all by $n$ we get $\frac {n^2}n < \frac nn < \frac {n^{-1}}n$ or $n < 1 < n^{-2}$.

So we have $0 < n < 1$.

I'll leave it to you to do the rest....

Well, no... I'll do II)  $n> 0$ so $n+n > n+0$ so $2n > n$.  So II) which say $2n < n$ is always false.

We could also have done that since $n> 0$ then $2n < n$ is true only if $\frac {2n}n < \frac nn$ or if $2 < 1$.  Since $2 > 1$ it can not be true.

Answer (score 3):

I'll keep the letter $n$ although using it to denote a real number is utterly unsatisfying. The image tells you that
$$n^2<n<\frac{1}{n}.$$
The first inequality is attained iff $0<n<1$ (¿why?). So the second inequality tells you nothing.

At first glance, (II) is wrong. Now, you can plug some specific values of $n$ (e. g. $n=1/2$) in the remaining inequalities to (possibly) get rid of the wrong ones. **Spoiler**: all of them are wrong.

Comment: I'd say I and IV are not true, but I wouldn't say they are "wrong".  They can be true for some but not all acceptable values of $n$. Wheres II and III are false for all acceptable values of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The information from the numberline gives two conditions

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
n-n^2 &>&0 \\
1/n-n&>&0
\end{array}$$

These conditions are satisfied when $0<n<1$

Then you need to check the four statements

$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
\text{I)}& n^4-n/4 &>&0 \\
\text{II)}& n-2n &>&0 \\
\text{III)}& n^{-3}-n^2 &>&0 \\
\text{IV)}& n^{-3}-(n-1/n)^{-2} &>&0 \\
\end{array}$$

The image below is a spoiler which shows that statement III is true, statement II is false, and statements I and IV can not be determined with the information. You can proof it algebraically for all those four cases. For example case II is simple $n-2n = -n>0$ or $n<0$ which is false when $0<n<1$.

[image: graphical example]